# IFrame policy for WebUSB in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, webusb

Is it possible to add support for the "usb" policy when Google Colab creates an IFrame for a code cell, for example:

```
import IPython
from google.colab import output

IPython.core.display.display(IPython.display.HTML('''
<button id="button">test</button>
<script>
  document.querySelector('#button').onclick = async () => {
    device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{
        vendorId: 0xABCD,
        classCode: 0xFF, // vendor-specific
        protocolCode: 0x01
    }]});
  };
</script>


'''))
```

creates an Iframe with:

```
<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; camera; gyroscope; magnetometer; microphone; serial; xr-spatial-tracking" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" src="https://ro7dmmbz8ec-496ff2e9c6d22116-0-colab.googleusercontent.com/outputframe.html?vrz=colab-20210722-060124-RC00_386208851" class="" style="height: 40px;"></iframe>
```

I would need to have "usb;" added to the list of the "allow" attribute. As I am currently getting the following error:

> VM10:3 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'USB': Access to the feature "usb" is disallowed by permissions policy.
> at HTMLButtonElement.document.querySelector.onclick (:3:34)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google Colaboratory is based on the Jupyter project. I found an [open issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3450) related to adding the necessary `allow` attribute to enable the Geolocation API in iframes within a notebook. The same attribute is required to enable APIs like WebUSB. I recommend opening an issue on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues) asking for WebUSB support specifically.

Comment: Thanks @reilly-grant - the same code cell works as is in Jupyter as it doesn't use IFrames. So I think the `allow` attribute is something that needs to change on the Google Colaboratory side - do you have any suggestions on where I can request this change?

Comment: I'm working with the Colab folks to deploy a fix.

Comment: It looks like my fix to Colab has been deployed, note that your original code has an error because it specifies `protocolCode` without specifying `subclassCode`.

Comment: Nice, I now see the "usb" value as part of the IFrame "allow" attribute on Google Colab! Thanks for resolving this!